# Facing Error in Sanity like Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: next.js, sanity

New with sanity
But facing a issue while trying to run with my project. I have latest version of sanity installed globally. but Every time i run my project I am facing this Error message

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Bad Request
Please upgrade to latest version of the Sanity CLI using `npm install -g @sanity/cli` and run `sanity login` to re-authenticate

Call Stack
Object.eval [as callback]
node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/http/request.js (46:0)
cbOnce
node_modules/@bjoerge/xhr/index.js (62:0)
loadFunc
node_modules/@bjoerge/xhr/index.js (138:0)
XMLHttpRequest.readystatechange
node_modules/@bjoerge/xhr/index.js (68:0)
```

I run this npm install -g @sanity/cli command many times but no progress..

My node -v is 16